# bitmap set pixel/pixels does not work

Tags: java, android

```
    TextView loadingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loadingText);
    loadingText.setTextSize(36);
    loadingText.setText("Morphing...");
    Bitmap leftbm = ((BitmapDrawable)leftImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Bitmap rightbm = ((BitmapDrawable)rightImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


    Bitmap newbm = leftbm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true);
    int[] pixels = new int[newbm.getHeight() * newbm.getWidth()];
    newbm.getPixels(pixels, 0, newbm.getWidth(), 0, 0, newbm.getWidth(), newbm.getHeight());

    if (!newbm.isMutable()) {
        Log.d("mutable check", "" + newbm.isMutable());
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newbm.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newbm.getHeight(); j++) {
            newbm.setHasAlpha(false);
            newbm.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
        }
    }

    loadingText.clearComposingText();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.morphView)).setImageBitmap(newbm);
```

This is my code for a button click method in my main activity. It only ever outputs a black image. I have done it both with alpha and without, or using set pixel or set pixels. Always getting the same result.

EDIT: My problem was using the wrong configuration when using the copy method (which I was using to get a mutable bitmap of my image) You need ALPHA_8888 not ALPHA_8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its your format.  You set it to ALPHA_8.  This format stores ONLY alpha, no color data.  User ARGB_8888 instead-  8 bits per color channel and an 8 bit alpha.